# Access Viewmodel in Fragment MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

When I compile this project https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport i get the error:

> The base class or interface 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.IMvxLayoutInflater' in assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' referenced by type 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView' could not be resolved  (CS0011) (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragging)

Please help!

Comment: You need to post the essential part of your code here.  Links are not enough.

Comment: You need to make sure all nugets are on the latest 4.0 beta. After that clear the cache and it will work

Comment: When I try to install nugets on 4.0 beta it says that 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore' already has a dependency defined for 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.Binding'. @Martijn00

Comment: You need at least nuget 2.8.6 to install. It is available in vs2015 or command line.

Comment: Look at my explenation here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1088#issuecomment-130408367